# How do I trim content to get desired string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How to trim values which end with `'`?

Example: I have more than 100k rows with column report name like report[@name='Air Bookings by Status Code']
The actual report name is just

`Air Bookings by Status Code`

How do I trim this string?
I tried doing

`substr(a.COGIPF_REPORTNAME, INSTR(a.COGIPF_REPORTNAME, '=', 1,1)+2, INSTR(a.COGIPF_REPORTNAME, ']')-2)`

I'm able to trip the first part. How do I do the latter part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp_substr:

```
regexp_substr(a.COGIPF_REPORTNAME,q'<'([^']*)'>',1,1,null,1)
```

Comment: The page says I have to wait for 5 minutes before I can mark :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have a version wihtout regex, you can also use "pure" SQL functions:

```
SUBSTR(a.COGIPF_REPORTNAME,
       INSTR(a.COGIPF_REPORTNAME, '=') + 2,
       LENGTH(a.COGIPF_REPORTNAME) - INSTR(a.COGIPF_REPORTNAME, '=') - 3)
```

Note that the second parameter to `SUBSTRING` is the length of the desired substring.

This works if it is known, that the text always terminates with `"']"`. Otherwise you will have to calculate the length differently:

```
SUBSTR(a.COGIPF_REPORTNAME,
       INSTR(a.COGIPF_REPORTNAME, '=') + 2,
       INSTR(a.COGIPF_REPORTNAME, ']') - INSTR(a.COGIPF_REPORTNAME, '=') - 3)
```

Why subtracting 3? Well - we have to subtract 2 for the two single quotes, but even if the text is empty, the position of the last single quote will be one more than that of the first single quote. Since an empty text has a length of 0, we must subtract one more.

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32454a/10